# php add new fields to the array and display it

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

The code given below is to read a csv file and retrieve the values to the fields $time,$sip,$dip and $data. I need to retrieve,

1. first_time_stamp
2. SIP/DIP
3. sum_of_all_values_at_SIP
4. sum_of_all_values_at_DIP

Below code is for the total sum up. But I can't find the sip and dip separately. I need to find sip and dip separately. Also the first time stamp.

```
    $lines =file('/ghgj.csv');
    $records=array();
    $i=1;
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {

     list($time,$sip,$dip,$data)= explode(',',$line);
     if(substr($sip, 0, 3 )=="10.")
     {
           if(key_exists($sip, $records))
           {
               $records[$sip] += $data;
           }
           else
           {
                $records[$sip] = $data;
           }

    }
    else if(substr($dip, 0, 3 )=="10." )
    {        
           if(key_exists($dip, $records))
           {
            $records[$dip] += $data;
           } 
           else 
           {
              $records[$dip] = $data;
           }
     }
     else 
     {
        continue;
     }
     $i++;  
     }
     }
```

The example of csv file is given below:

```
2014-10-31 23:34:06,10.101.11.122,54.252.136.82,2047
2014-10-31 23:34:08,31.13.70.81,10.101.84.6,49580
2014-10-31 23:34:15,10.101.11.122,54.252.136.82,20
2014-10-31 23:34:09,54.252.136.82,10.101.11.122,20
2014-10-31 23:34:12,10.101.11.13,10.101.11.122,20
```

Eg:Output of my code:

```
10.101.11.122(sip or dip),2087
10.101.84.6,49580
10.101.11.13,20
```

Eg:Output should Looks like:

```
2014-10-31 23:34:06(timestamp),10.101.11.122(common sip or dip),2067(sum of sip),20(sum of dip)
2014-10-31 23:34:08,10.101.84.6,0,49580
2014-10-31 23:34:06,10.101.11.13,20,0
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you taken a look at [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)? Might be helpful in your situation... Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you. As @jerdiggity wrote, you can also use fgetcsv(), but in your case (no quotes, and in particular no quoted commas or newlines in your CSV data), it's not necessary.

```
$lines =file('/ghgj.csv');
$records=array();
$i=1;
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    list($time,$sip,$dip,$data)= explode(',',$line);
    if(substr($sip, 0, 3 )=="10.")
    {
        if (!key_exists($sip, $records))
        {
            $records[$sip] = array(
                'timestamp' => $time,
                'sip'       =>     0,
                'dip'       =>     0
            );
        }
        $records[$sip]['sip'] += $data;
    }
    else if(substr($dip, 0, 3 )=="10." )
    {        
        if (!key_exists($dip, $records))
        {
            $records[$dip] = array(
                'timestamp' => $time,
                'sip'       =>     0,
                'dip'       =>     0
            );
        }
        $records[$dip]['dip'] += $data;
    }
    else 
    {
        continue;
    }
    $i++;  
}
```